# How to increase order size for each entry in a pyramiding strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Please help me in figuring a way to increase size of each entry when in a pyramiding strategy. My basic code is below that is not working.

```
lastEntrySize = strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1)

long = ta.crossover(close,lowerBandValue)

_qty = input(0.10, "% increase for each entry")

if long and strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=close)

if long and strategy.opentrades > 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=close, qty=lastEntrySize+lastEntrySize*_qty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I assume your order size is set to 1 contract which the default value. Some markets won't allow you to have any decimals in your contract size.

You can change your order size value to use 100% of your equity or start entering with 10 contracts and see that it works that way. Just set your contract size based on your needs and you will be good.

100% of equity:
[image]

10 contracts:
[image]

Comment: I get a Study Error "Invalid qty value (-8861.000000)"

Comment: Well, then check your calculation.